# React update values only once

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a newb question :)

I have a modal that opens in React Native with a dropdown select that requires values. I want to calculate the values whenever the modal opens.

```
let pickupTime; // Set a value that can be overwritten. I'm not using State because I want this value to change whenever I open the modal again.
const pickupTimeOptions = useRef([{ label: "", value: "" }]); // A ref to store the values
useEffect(() => {
  const pickup_hours_today = business.pickup_hours_today; // Array of strings I pass to the modal.
  console.log("pickup_hours_today", pickup_hours_today);        
  const options = pickup_hours_today.map((time) => {
    return {
      label: time,
      value: time,
    };
  });
  pickupTimeOptions.current = options;
}, [business.pickup_hours_today]);
console.log("pickupTimeOptions", pickupTimeOptions); // Let's see if we got it
```

The problem is that the ref never updates. The log prints this:

```
pickupTimeOptions Object {
  "current": Array [
    Object {
      "label": "",
      "value": "",
    },
  ],
}
pickup_hours_today Array [
  ... // the string array of hours
]
Should be updating the ref
pickupTimeOptions Object {
  "current": Array [
    Object {
      "label": "",
      "value": "",
    },
  ],
}
pickup_hours_today Array [
  ...
]
Should be updating the ref
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I handle this differently? I don't mind using state, but when I tried, it kept updating it whenever I selected a different values with the dropdown picker.

Comment: Why have a ref at all? Your dropdown options are deterministic based on your state, so use the state. `<Dropdown options={business.pickup_hours_today.map(...)} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the order of console logs, it'll explain what's happening.

This is printed first, meaning calculation in `useEffect` hasn't happened yet

```
console.log("pickupTimeOptions", pickupTimeOptions); // Let's see if we got it
```

According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) `useEffect` is only called after the render. You need to do the calculation before or during the render cycle.

You can use `useMemo` which is executed during rendering. Refer to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for more details

Your updated code should look something like this

```
let pickupTime; // Set a value that can be overwritten. I'm not using State because I want this value to change whenever I open the modal again.
const pickupTimeOptions = useMemo(() => {
  const pickup_hours_today = business.pickup_hours_today; // Array of strings I pass to the modal.
  console.log("pickup_hours_today", pickup_hours_today);        
  const options = pickup_hours_today.map((time) => {
    return {
      label: time,
      value: time,
    };
  });
  return options;
}, [business.pickup_hours_today]);
console.log("pickupTimeOptions", pickupTimeOptions); // Let's see if we got it
```